# Запуск скрипта/программы от имени администратора Windows 7/10

Tags: windows, безопасность, реестр

Необходимо внести информацию в реестр для большого количества пользователей. 
У пользователя нет прав администратора.
Необходимо чтобы пользователь запустил программу, она запустилась с правами администратора и внесла необходимые данные в реестр.
Возможно ли это как то сделать?
Логин и пароль администратора заранее известен.

Comment: Можно чуть точнее? Что за прога, какие данные?

Comment: Есть обычный reg файл, который нужно запустить у обычного пользователя без прав админа. Это нужно сделать один раз, просто чтобы происались нужные данные. Можно через bat, можно еще как то, я просто пока не понимаю как это сделать можно. Суть в том, чтобы пользователь запустил этот файлик и данные прописались в реестр без запроса пароля админа. Может как то можно прописать заранее логин и пароль админа и в фоновом режиме выполнить это

Comment: Ну в GPO это штатный функционал. Используй его.

Comment: Как я понимаю групповые политики могут применяться к компьютерам подключенным к сети? А если он не подключен? (Может и не прав, никогда не имел дело с политиками)

Comment: `А если он не подключен?` значит подключи.